# A Doubt involving Variance Equation and Expectations

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value

Consider the following,

$$
\begin{alignedat}{1}
\operatorname{Var}(X)&=E((X-E(X))^2)\\&=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2.
\end{alignedat}
$$
Since the expectation of a random variable is no longer random, let $c = E(X)$:

$$
\begin{alignedat}{1}
\operatorname{Var}(X)&=E(X^2)-c^2\\&=E(X^2-c^2)\\&=E((X+c)(X-c))\\&=E((X+E(X))(X-E(X))).
\end{alignedat}
$$

However,
$$\operatorname{Var}(X)=E((X-E(X))^2)\not=E((X-E(X))(X+E(X))).$$

What happened?

Comment: How do you **know** that $E[(X-E[X])^2]$ _does not equal_ $E[(X-E[X])(X+E[X])]$? Because the formulas _look_ different?

Comment: @DilipSarwate In my response to Veljiko's answer below I gave a counterexample to their equality.

Answer (score 2):

$V(X)=E((X-E(X))^2)=E(X^2-2XE(X)+(E(X))^2)=E(X^2)-2E(X)E(X)+(E(X))^2 = E(X^2)-(E(X))^2=E(X^2)-c^2$

Comment: So they are the same, actually.

Comment: But they aren't. The variance has no sign influence; however, my conclusion from working backwards has just that. For example, if you used $V'(X)=E((X+E(X))(X-E(X)))$ for $X\sim\text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ you would get $V'(X)\not=\sigma^2$ for all $\mu\not=0$. The equality you showed above was that which was presented in my question.

Comment: I just realized my counterexample may not be correct. I am also doubting the sign influence since $X+E(X)$ taxes the part above mean greater than that below and they cancel out to yield the variance.